# Apollo server express - How to enable tracing in Apollo introspective playground?

Tags: apollo-server

I've searched the internet to find an example that implemented `apollo-server-express` tracing with no success.

I'm trying to enable tracing in apollo introspective playground however, I've managed "manually" adding the time using a custom plugin implementation, but was thinking if that is the best practice? The introspective is showing wrong time for the request and this is also not sure why!

This is my plugin. This plugin using sentry for performance tracking too. Sentry works perfect, but we need something faster for development here.

```js
/**
 * To read more about apollo server plugins @see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/integrations/plugins/
 * */
import {
  ApolloServerPlugin,
  GraphQLFieldResolverParams,
  GraphQLRequestContextWillSendResponse,
  GraphQLRequestListener,
} from 'apollo-server-plugin-base';

import {Context} from '../models';

const sentryPlugin: ApolloServerPlugin<Context> = {
  async requestDidStart({
    request,
    context,
  }): Promise<GraphQLRequestListener<Context>> {
    const startTime = new Date().getTime();
    if (request.operationName)
      context.sentryTransaction.setName(request.operationName!);

    return {
      async executionDidStart() {
        return {
          willResolveField(
            reqContext: GraphQLFieldResolverParams<any, Context>
          ) {
            // hook for each new resolver
            const span = reqContext.context.sentryTransaction.startChild({
              op: 'resolver',
              description: `${reqContext.info.parentType.name}.${reqContext.info.fieldName}`,
            });
            
            return () => {
              // this will execute once the resolver is finished
              span.finish();
            };
          },
        };
      },
      async willSendResponse(
        requestContext: GraphQLRequestContextWillSendResponse<Context>
      ) {
        const endTime = new Date().getTime();
        requestContext.response.extensions = {
          ...requestContext.response.extensions,
          tracing: {
            version: 1,
            startTime: new Date(startTime).toISOString(),
            endTime: new Date(endTime).toISOString(),
            duration: endTime - startTime, // <<== the time here is correct but introspective show it wrong!!
            execution: {
              resolvers: [], // <<=== This array is for each field. I'm sure that should not be manually implemented therefor I left it empty.
            },
          },
        };

        // hook for transaction finished
        requestContext.context.sentryTransaction.finish();
      },
    };
  },
};

export default sentryPlugin;
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is apollo-server-express@2.x (guessing from the comment above your code), I believe you just need to pass "tracing: true":

```js
const server = new ApolloServer({
  ...otherConfig,
  tracing: true
})
```

I've also seen some cases of

```js
new ApolloServer({
  plugins: [
    require('apollo-tracing').plugin()
  ]
})
```

Comment: Hi Dan, Thank you for your kind participation
Unfortunately, we are using

` "Apollo-server-express": "^3. 4.0",`

Also regarding to `apollo-tracing`, they mentioned that is no longer used in v3 which make sense because typescript complain as soon I add tracing key.

Comment: To be fair, they specifically say to use my second example in the v3 documentation. They do say that "it might not work", but they also say to file an issue if it doesn't.